# SELECT from result of UPDATE ... RETURNING in jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm transforming some old PostgreSQL code to jOOQ, and I'm currently struggling with SQL that has multiple `WITH` clauses, where each one depends on previous. It would be best to keep the SQL logic the way it was written and not to change it (e.g. multiple queries to DB).

As it seems, there is no way to do SELECT on something that is UPDATE ... RETURNING, for example

```
dsl.select(DSL.asterisk())
   .from(dsl.update(...)
            .returning(DSL.asterisk())
   )
```

I've created some test tables, trying to create some sort of MVCE:

```sql
create table dashboard.test (id int primary key not null, data text); --test table

with updated_test AS (
    UPDATE dashboard.test SET data = 'new data'
    WHERE id = 1
    returning data
),
    test_user AS (
        select du.* from dashboard.dashboard_user du, updated_test -- from previous WITH
        where du.is_active AND du.data = updated_test.data
    )
SELECT jsonb_build_object('test_user', to_jsonb(tu.*), 'updated_test', to_jsonb(ut.*))
FROM test_user tu, updated_test ut; -- from both WITH clauses
```

So far this is my jOOQ code (written in Kotlin):

```kotlin
dsl.with("updated_test").`as`(
                dsl.update(Tables.TEST)
                        .set(Tables.TEST.DATA, DSL.value("new data"))
                        .returning(Tables.TEST.DATA) //ERROR is here: Required Select<*>, found UpdateResultStep<TestRecord>
        ).with("test_user").`as`(
                dsl
                        .select(DSL.asterisk())
                        .from(
                                Tables.DASHBOARD_USER,
                                DSL.table(DSL.name("updated_test")) //or what to use here?
                        )
                        .where(Tables.DASHBOARD_USER.IS_ACTIVE.isTrue
                                .and(Tables.DASHBOARD_USER.DATA.eq(DSL.field(DSL.name("updated_test.data"), String::class.java)))
                        )

        )
                .select() //here goes my own logic for jsonBBuildObject (which is tested and works for other queries)
                .from(
                        DSL.table(DSL.name("updated_test")), //what to use here
                        DSL.table(DSL.name("test_user")) //or here
                )
```

Are there any workarounds for this? I'd like to avoid changing SQL if possible.
Also, in this project this trick is used very often to get JSON(B) from UPDATE clause (table has JSON(B) columns too):

```sql
with _updated AS (update dashboard.test SET data = 'something' WHERE id = 1 returning *)
select to_jsonb(_updated.*) from _updated;
```

and it will be a real step back for us if there is no workaround for this.

I'm using JOOQ version `3.13.3`, and Postgres 12.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported in jOOQ, see:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3185
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4474

The workaround is, as always, when some vendor specific syntax is unsupported, to resort to [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)

E.g.

```java
// If you don't need to map data types
dsl.fetch("with t as ({0}) {1}", update, select);

// If you need to map data types
dsl.resultQuery("with t as ({0}) {1}", update, select).coerce(select.getSelect()).fetch();
```

Comment: Thank you Lukas for answer. `DSLContext::fetch` workaround is what I need here!